# Staying up at night

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, commas

I'm trying to describe two people who stay up at night to get some work done. Are the following sentences all grammatically correct and equivalent?

> Without sleeping we go on to finish
>   our work.
>
> Without sleep we go on to finish our
>   work.
>
> We unsleepingly go on to finish our
>   work.

Is there anything wrong or awkward about any of the above?

Comment: Number three reads a bit awkward to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add commas to the first two, but otherwise they each say almost the same thing.

1. There is a slight possibility that we mean that we do not sleep *while* we finish our work:

   > Without sleeping, we go on to finish
   >   our work.
2. We are going without sleep, either before or while finishing:

   > Without sleep, we go on to finish our
   >   work.
3. I have never heard "unsleepingly" used, and the OED only has one citation for it, but it is correct. I think it carries more a of a sense of "watchfulness".

   > We unsleepingly go on to finish our
   >   work.

Answer (score 2):

All are correct, but there is a subtle difference in meaning:

> Without sleeping, we go on to finish our work.

Here, you emphasize the choice or contrast: we *could* have slept, or we *wanted* to sleep, but instead, we go on to finish our work.

> Without sleep, we go on to finish our work.

Here, there's less of a sense that we could have slept right now; maybe we were up the night before, and now we're tired.  This form brings that deficit (without sleep--tired) more into focus.

> We unsleepingly go on to finish our work.

Unsleepingly is almost never used, and carries a connotation that we don't need or desire or miss sleep, even if some might think we ought to.

> We sleeplessly go on to finish our work.

You didn't mention this one, but this suggests that we would have trouble going to sleep even if we tried; maybe the work is too engaging, or maybe we just have insomnia.

Answer (score 2):

All of these sound somewhat awkward to me. Also "Unsleepingly" is not a common word, if it is one you haven't just invented.

"We go on to finish our work without sleep(ing)" represents a more natural ordering of the various parts of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*unsleepingly* sounds a bit silly, but I think the other two are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

We went on to finish our work without sleeping.